# InnoDB: mmap(68878336 bytes) failed; errno 12

Tags: centos, mysql, innodb, centos7, mariadb

The screenshots explain everything, first I try to start it, and it won't, so I check the status, then I check the logs.

[image: error]
[image]
[image]

After following a number of previous suggestions that I founder around StackExchange, my.cnf contents are:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
performance_schema=off
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64MB
innodb_purge_threads=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Comment: And how much memory do you have?

Comment: I'm on the 512 MB plan with Digital Ocean. It's an empty server. Does not have too much running.

Answer (score 1):

Change your configuration file using a smaller value for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

For example, use `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8M`

Answer (score 0):

This post might help you. Basically you are running out of memory. Try to lower down max_connection variable and other parameters.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/why-does-mysql-say-im-out-of-memory